# Hour by step of 2 hours in the form H:M on the x axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a plot with ggplot:

```
foo$time<-format(as.POSIXct(foo$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), format="%H:%M")
p<-ggplot(data=foo,aes(x=time,y=rm)) + geom_point()

p<-p+labs(x="Hour")
p<-p+labs(y = "std")

p<-p+theme_bw()
p<-p+theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
 panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
 panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
 panel.border = element_blank(),
 panel.background = element_blank())
```

How to receive on x axis, labels in the form of that they hour will be ex. every two hours? I tried to: 
`p+scale_x_datetime(breaks=date_breaks('2 hour'),labels=date_format('%H:%M'))`

but it gives me "Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only".

I have a big .csv file with data. So, I cannot put it here. I have two columns and many rows. They look as:

Date    rm

2017-06-23 00:10    1.127

2017-06-23 00:10    1.26339

2017-06-23 00:20    1.12279

Comment: I can help u, but i need ur data

Comment: I have a big .csv file, and as far as i know, I cannot attach it here. I have many rows of that kind: 

2017-06-23 00:10 1.127

Comment: look my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i test it:

```
requires(dplyr)

    b <- expand.grid(test_date = seq(ymd_hms("2017-04-27 22:00:00"), ymd_hms("2017-05-11 18:00:00"), by = "hour"))
    b <- b%>%mutate(x = seq(1:333))

ggplot(b, aes(x=test_date, y=x)) + geom_line() +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "2 hours", date_labels = "%H:%M")
```

I created a table with 2 columns, the first column is the datetime with format POSIXct, the second is the number. U should write:

```
ggplot(data = foo,aes(x = time,y = rm)) + geom_point() + scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "2 hours", date_labels = "%H:%M")
```

Comment: i need str(foo)

Comment: I didn't manage to check your example, because it gives me error "could not find function "%>%". On my it doesn't work. error is the same as in my question "Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only".  str(foo) gives:
 'data.frame':   143 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Date            : Factor w/ 143 levels "2017-06-23 00:10",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ rm: num  1.127 1.123 1.03 0.969 0.966 ...
 $ time            : chr  "00:10" "00:20" "00:30" "00:40" ...

Comment: try this: foo$date <- as.POSIXct(foo$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC") and add str(foo) again

Comment: 'data.frame':   143 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Date            : Factor w/ 143 levels "2017-06-23 00:10",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ rm: num  1.127 1.123 1.03 0.969 0.966 ...
 $ hour            : chr  "00:10" "00:20" "00:30" "00:40" ...
 $ date            : POSIXct, format: NA NA ...

Comment: u says that u have 2 columns, date and numbers. You should do the following:
1) dont create a new column with time.
2) on a clear dataframe use this foo$date <- as.POSIXct(foo$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
3) use ggplot in my answer

if it had another error, add this

Comment: Maybe if u dont have a seconds u should write:
foo$date <- as.POSIXct(foo$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "UTC")

Comment: There is no difference if I add previously time or not. I checked. Your  foo$date <- as.POSIXct(foo$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC") gives a column with NA values.

Comment: foo$date <- as.POSIXct(foo$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "UTC") if u doesnt have a seconds, if it dont work, use firstly as.character(), then as.POSIXct

Comment: Yes, sure.It has to be without seconds. It works! Thank you very very much!:)

Comment: Was glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

```
install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)

foo$time <- hm(foo$time)

p + scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "2 hours", date_labels = "%H:%M")
```

Please replace with this and check if the error still persists.

Comment: Can you please check the class of foo$time

Comment: It is a "character"

Comment: As I write edit(), I get many lines with many things, so I have no idea what next. There is no word "error" there.

Comment: I think you need to update the question with a sample data.